# Python и гугл шитс

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

Может кто подскажет, не могу понять как мне связать питон и гугл ишитс. Шитс по апи получилось связать. Мне надо чтобы питон находил значение в столбце A и проверял если в столбце В по найденному значению в А, значение меньше 200, больше 500 и тп, тогда действие.
Я не понимаю как обратиться к столбцам. Пока получилось так и это не работает, только нахожу значения в А.

```
async def on_ready():
    # Перебираем все сервера в которых находится бот
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:  
                id = member.name
                id2 = member.discriminator
                a=str(id)+"#"+str(id2)
                int_lst = [int(x) for x in values_list1]
                for a in values_list: 
                    for i in int_lst:
                        
                            if i<200:
                                print(i)

    else:
                    print(a,"не нашлось")
client.run(token)
```

Как мне через питон сделать посик и условие по столбцам

ексель выглядит так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы водили values_list  и int_lst. Что там внутри?

Comment: Добрый день! Там ссылка лист гугл шитс, те я сначала sht2 = gc.open_by_url('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=1KJ...O2DGI'), потом values_list = worksheet.col_values(1) и inst list тоже ссылка на столбец В